# JDK 6 on Arch Linux ARM (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: java, arm, raspberry-pi, archlinux

I need a JDK 6 or lower (**not** JDK 7 or 8) on my Arch Linux ARM device (Raspberry Pi). Does anyone know where to find such a package, either binary or source? Arch Linux by default only provides a JDK 7 package via `pacman`.

By the way: I already tried AUR via `yaourt` but didn't manage to compile any of the JDK 6 packages provided there.

Comment: I need a JDK, not just a JRE.

Comment: boomer! :) sorry I missed that. so you don't want to use another machine to make the compilations?

Comment: Correct. Java compilation is only a small part of an automated multi-language build.

Comment: It might be better to move this question to superuser.com or raspberrypi.stackexchange.com